# Condtional Statement in XML Layout Files

Tags: android

I am making an Android application in which every member has up to 5 children, thus I need to show children dynamically. However, I can't apply conditions on XML layouts.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: hey man i m really new to stackoverflow , n i dont understand this bounty thing , have i done anything wrong ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your xml code you can make your layouts

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

to have them not showing and in you mainActivity (java code) you make them show up using

```
LayoutView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// or
LayoutView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //depending on the case
```

I normally make my layouts to have other layouts horizontally or vertically with buttons textviews etc. (child fields)  show or disappear at a button click event.

Comment: actually i am getting the no of child from a domain class , so its not a matter of hiding , i need to pass diff no child icons dynamically

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid you should paste some code so we could see what you are trying to do and what you are using, that way we could help a little bit more accurate.

Comment: well this solutions seems to be enough , i havent tried it properly yet , thanx , now its done

Answer (score 1):

That is what java code is for. You create xml layouts for activities and widgets and then you manipulate them in Java.